# Where in my nuxt3/vue3 app do i put the loading of initial data/json?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

Quick question here. Its more of a conceptual question rather then code related (since i know how to write the code for it).

What i wondering is where in the application is best practise to load som initial json?

It's a one page app so i only have an app.vue and a route to a component/page which is the index, and only page. Should i put the async logic in the app.vue or in my component/page?

/Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can really do it either way since with such a small project it does not matter much. I would suggest app.vue if the data is more "global" to the app, and the page/component when the data is significant to that page only.